# Run gulp tasks on middleman build execution

Tags: javascript, ruby, gulp, middleman

Is it possible to run gulpfile tasks during middleman build process? Tried searching for this, but wasn't able to find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using a [custom extension](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/custom_extensions/).

For example, if you want to run your gulp tasks at the end of the build cycle, you could create an `after_build` extension like this:

In **config.rb**:

```
class MyFeature < Middleman::Extension
  def initialize(app, options_hash={}, &block)
    super
    app.after_build do |builder|
      builder.run 'gulp default'
    end
  end
end
::Middleman::Extensions.register(:my_feature, MyFeature)

activate :my_feature
```

I tested the above with gulp installed (`npm install --global gulp`) and the following **gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  console.log('Hello, world');
});
```

and after running `middleman build` I get output like the following:

```
[21:25:24] Using gulpfile ~/dev/projects/demo/gulpfile.js
[21:25:24] Starting 'default'...
Hello, world
[21:25:24] Finished 'default' after 98 μs
```

The [extension docs](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/custom_extensions/) have other examples of extensions that allow you to hook into other areas of Middleman for similar purposes.

**Edit**
Example of `after_configuration` (untested):

```
class MyFeature < Middleman::Extension
  def initialize(app, options_hash={}, &block)
    super
  end

  def after_configuration
    # add your pre-build, post config.rb execution code here...
    `gulp default`
  end
end
```

Comment: One more question, is there a way to run gulp before build, as I have some files ignored in order to keep build folder clean.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to hook into the `after_configuration` and `before` callbacks. `after_configuration` is called right after config.rb is executed, but before any building happens. `before` is called right before any page is rendered. [the custom extension docs](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/custom_extensions/) show examples of implementing both of these. I think `after_configuration` is likely what you are looking for.